# How do autocomplete() works?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, search-engine, jquery-autocomplete

When I try to implement auto-complete using the code below I get nothing (no result, no error):

```
$('#keyword').autocomplete({
    source : '/Dev/pages/search.php',
    minLength : 3,
    type : 'POST',
    select: function( event, ui )
    {
         $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.addClass("yellow");
    }
})
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )
{
    console.log(item);
    return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + add3Dots(item.name,20) + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
 };
```

---

```
if(isset($_POST['term'])) {
        //Word enter by user
        $q = htmlentities($_POST['term']);

        $search = connection::bdd_test();
        $query = "SELECT name from BDD_TEST.companies WHERE name LIKE '%".$q."%' ORDER BY name asc";

        $result = $search->query($query);

        while($data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
           $data['name'];
        }    
}
else 
{
    $data['call']=false;
    $data['message']="Problem to collect word";

}


echo json_encode($data);
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

I think it could be data(), but i'm not sure.

Comment: <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"></ul><span role="status" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><div>No search results.</div></span></body></html>

Comment: The datasource is a `server-side` script which returns `JSON data`, specified via a simple URL for the source-option. check it out.

Comment: @FrayneKonok I've checked server-side script, and now it's ok. 

But now i obtain "No search result.". 
I added the php script in my 1st post and i think it's because of '$_POST['term']' which is probably empty.

Comment: Your PHP part has some problem. [Learn here, how to create a php for json](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step). I think this link solve your problem.

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for [jquery-autocomplete-server-side-matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873513/jquery-autocomplete-server-side-matching)

Comment: Thank you for the documentation! I tried sending a JSON array with values ​​I inserted without database query and it works well when i make search. I think the problem is the recovery of the word in the input because the condition isset ( $ _ POST [ 'term' ] ) isn't true, I've also tried isset ( $ _ GET [ 'term' ] ), but nothing works.

Comment: so you are still not getting the output.

Comment: your PHP code is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP - search.php**

```
$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();

$search = connection::bdd_test();
$query = "SELECT name from BDD_TEST.companies ORDER BY name asc";

$result = $search->query($query);
while($data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $a_json_row["name"] = $data['name'];
    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);       
}
$json = json_encode($a_json);
print_r($json);
```

**jQuery-ui Autocomplete**

```
$( "#keyword" ).autocomplete({
  source: "/Dev/pages/search.php",
  minLength: 3,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.addClass("yellow");
  }
});
```

**Make sure something:**

1. your data connection is ok or not.
2. source is valid or not.

I think if everything is okey, then the code will work fine.