# How Use Select 2 and Json to display a big DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have a problem displaying the data in the dropdown list using select2. I think the reason is the Query returning many rows. when I limit the number of Row to 50 (where Rownum <=100 ) the data displayed but when I remove the where condition no data display. The PatientDemo table has more than 600000 rows Any help how to solve this issue. I am using Orcale and C#

View

```
<link href="~/Content/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron">
<input type="hidden" id="textBoxVal" />
<select class="mySelect2" style="width:500px;">
</select>
</div>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mySelect2").select2({
        placeholder: "Select category",
        allowClear: true,
        theme: "classic",
        ajax: {
            url: "/Home/GetCategory",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 10000,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    searchTerm: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }
        }
    });
   });
  $(".mySelect2").on("change", function () {
    var catId = $(this).val();
    $("#textBoxVal").val(catId);

    var textBoxValueData = $("#textBoxVal").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Save?data=' + textBoxValueData,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
    });
});
```

Model

```
public class Select2Model
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

C#

```
 public JsonResult GetCategory(string searchTerm)
    {
        var list = new List<Select2Model>();
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PatientRecord"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT PATIENT, NAMEFORWARD  FROM PATIENTDEMO ";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Select2Model()
                {
                    text = rdr["NAMEFORWARD"].ToString(),
                    id = rdr["Patient"].ToString()
                });
            }
            var dataList = list.ToList();
            if (searchTerm != null)
            {
               dataList = list.Where(x => x.text.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList();
            }
            var modifiedData = dataList.Select(x => new {
                id = x.id,
                text = x.text
            });
            return Json(modifiedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    public JsonResult Save(string data)
    {
        return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

600000 rows in a drop down list is not a user friendly one. Instead why don't you implement a drop down list with auto complete?

[image]

Check the example at the bottom of this page: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

**Update:**
In your case you source would be a ajax call to the server side to pull the relevant data. Like this:

```
$('#myautocomplete').autocomplete({
            type: "POST",
            minLength: 3,
            source : function (request, response) 
            {                         
                var source_url = "../handlers/MyLookup.ashx?someparameter=" + $("#someparameter").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: source_url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: request,
                    success: function (data) { response(data); },
                    error : function (a,b,c) { HandleLookUpError(a); }
                    });
            },                
            select: function (event, ui) { $('#result').val(ui.item.id); }               
        });
```

Note the `source_url` variable and the ajax call in the above code.
More details on how to load data from server side is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873641/218408

Comment: thanks for your reply any idea how I can pass the Json return in the $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ json return here  ]
});

Comment: Do not load the full Json. Json will be too big again. See my updated answer. Hope that helps.